# List<Object> into Map in salesforce

Tags: map

I have the following (List arguments) as a param to the method. I converted the list into Map in the following way.

```
Map<Integer,String> nMap = new Map<Integer,String>();
for(Integer i=0;i<arguments.size();i++) {
            nMap.put(i,(String.valueOf(arguments[i])));
            system.debug('nMap1' + nMap.get(i));
       }
```

My debug is like the following way:

```
nMap1{Active=Y, Address=4416 ROOSEVELT DR, MIDLAND, TX 79703-5412, AmsVal=Remote, BillingPeriod=1/29/2018 - 2/26/2018, City=MIDLAND, CriticalCareExpDate=, CriticalCareValue=null, CriticalText=, CrmContract=5010838603, ESIID=10443720003479080, ...}
nMap1{Active=N, Address=4416 ROOSEVELT DR, MIDLAND, TX 79703-5412, AmsVal=Remote, BillingPeriod=12/29/2016 - 1/22/2017, City=MIDLAND, CriticalCareExpDate=, CriticalCareValue=null, CriticalText=, CrmContract=5009304650, ESIID=10443720003479080, ...}
```

Out of these i require only `Active`, `Address` and `ESIID`. How to pick those values alone

Comment: Include the list of argument as well in your question.

Comment: for the method they are passing String GetServiceResponse(List<Object> arguments). In the arguments all the nMap values

Comment: Are you receiving a list of key-value pairs? Right now, this code is just mapping integer indices to array items, which isn't very useful (it's a less-efficient version of an array).

Comment: I hope that's not real data, since that is an actual home address in Midland, TX. If you've included real persons' data, please edit it out.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not 100% clear, but I assume that your method accepts a list of sObject or a List of Map (as I can see from your debug).
The following code uses a list of sObjects:

```
public static Map<Integer, Map<String,Object> > yourMethod(List<sObject> arguments) {
    Set<String> fieldsToSave = new Set<String>{'Active','Address','ESIID'};
    Map<Integer, Map<String,Object> > nMap = new Map<Integer, Map<String,Object> >();
    for (Integer i=0;i<arguments.size();i++)
    {
        Map<String,Object> sObjectMap = new Map<String,Object>();
        for (String field:fieldsToSave)
        {
            sObjectMap.put(field, arguments[i].get(field) );
        }
        nMap.put(i,sObjectMap);
    }
    return nMap;
}
```

However, a Map which keys are 1,2,3.. Isn't that a List?

Comment: Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void get(String) from the type Object at line 424 column 36 if i am pasting this code...

Comment: I've made a conversion in order to make things work: the method accepts a list of sObject instead of Object... Every variable in Apex can be an Object, what's the real type of the objects in the arguments list? List<sObject>? List< Map<String,Object>>?